# React is not defined...html file

Tags: reactjs

I'm hoping to learn react by following this tutorial from Egghead.  In this early lesson Kent Dodds loads the React libraries and uses them on his page:https://egghead.io/lessons/react-write-hello-world-with-raw-react-apis

When I load the following code in a browser I get a "React is not defined" error in the console.

```
<div id="root"></div>
<script scr='https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0-rc.3/umd/react.development.js'></script>
<script scr='https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.0.0-rc.3/umd/react-dom.development.js'></script>
<script type"text/javascript">
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
const element = React.createEelement('div', {className: 'container', children: 'Hello World '})
ReactDOM.render(element, rootElement)
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: typo error .Its not `scr` should be `src`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `scr` for `src` in your scripts ;)

```
<script src='https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0-rc.3/umd/react.development.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.0.0-rc.3/umd/react-dom.development.js'></script>
```

Also, another typo:

```
const element = React.createElement('div', {className: 'container', children: 'Hello World '})
```